# Terminology for non-game theoretic techniques

Tags: terminology, game-theory

When solving an adversarial problem there are two basic approaches: one that takes into account the thinking process of both sides, and as opposed to that the non-psychological computations.

For example, in poker a computer can be programmed to simply compute the "best" moves for both sides, or alternatively could try to infer what the opponent is doing based on psychological considerations. This perhaps could be called game theoretic calculation, but that term is usually associated with games that involve a cooperative element. Although poker does have a small cooperative aspect to it, mostly it is adversarial, so I guess the term game theoretic may or may not apply to poker, depending on how you define that term and characterize poker.

In any case, what terminology can I use to discriminate between computational methodologies that involve human psychology versus those that do not?

Currently, I am just saying "game theoretic" and "non-game theoretic" approaches, but I wonder if there is a better set of terminology?